# How does javac automatically compile dependencies of a class

Tags: java, import, package, javac

Given the following directory structure:

```
/top
   |--- wrk
          |--- pkg
                  |--- A.java
                  |--- B.java
```

Assume that the two files `A.java` and `B.java` contain the following code, respectively:

```
// Filename: A.java
package pkg;
class A { B b; }

// Filename: B.java
package pkg;
class B {...}
```

Assuming that the current directory is `/top/wrk`

Why does the command `javac -cp . pkg/A.java` work successfully even though we have not yet compiled `B.java`?

Also if the current directory is `/top/wrk/pkg` then the command `javac A.java` works. How so?

Comment: The answer lies in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCCHDGH . No time to reproduce this here in form of an answer, for short, roughly: It also looks for source files in the classpath.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. It fails to compile on my machine. Are you sure that B has never been compiled?

Comment: It's a Mac / Windows thing. See my edited and now (hopefully) definitive answer for more detail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why does the command javac -cp . pkg/A.java work successfully even though we have not yet compiled B.java

When you compile `A.java`, the compiler will compile `B.java` as well since both `A.java` and `B.java` are in the same package. This will work even If `B.java` was in a different package from `A.java` (provided `B` is public) as long as both the packages are present in the `wrk` directory and you compile `A.java` from `wrk` directory.

From the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) for `javac`  :

> If the -sourcepath option is not specified, the user class path is also searched for source files.

From the [Oracle document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) for `CLASSPATH`

> The default value of the class path is "."

If you haven't set a `CLASSPATH`, it will be defaulted to `.`. Subsequently, the `sourcepath` will also be `.` since the default `sourcepath` is the same as the `CLASSPATH`. You can confirm that the default sourcepath is set to `.` by compiling `A.java` using `javac -verbose -g pkg\A.java`. Notice that the compiler is looking in the current directory for `.java` files :

`[parsing started pkg\A.java]
 [parsing completed 29ms]
 [search path for source files: [.]]`

To confirm that the `sourcepath` is set to `CLASSPATH`, you can try changing the `CLASSPATH` using the `-cp` option by compiling `A.java` using `javac -cp C:\ -verbose -g pkg\A.java`. `A.java` will not compile this time since you have overwritten the `CLASSPATH` to `C:\` and that's what `sourcepath` will default to as well. This is the output :

`[parsing started pkg\A.java]
 [parsing completed 26ms]
 [search path for source files: [C:\]]
 pkg\A.java:3: cannot find symbol
 symbol  : class B`

> Also if the current directory is /top/wrk/pkg then the command javac
>   A.java works. How so?

This will not work regardless of whether `B.class` is present in `pkg`

**Disclaimer :** I can only confirm this behavior on Windows but I highly doubt that it should be any different on other operating systems.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the javac docs that specifies this behaviour? I couldn't find anything other than through specifying -sourcepath.

Comment: @PhilAnderson See my edit. Chances are that you have some value set in `CLASSPATH` so your `sourcepath` does not default to `.`

Comment: Thanks Chetan, but I haven't got anything in the CLASSPATH.

Comment: @PhilAnderson Can you try compiling `A.java` using `javac -cp . pkg\A.java`? If it works, this confirms that `sourcepath` is defaulted to `CLASSPATH`

Comment: As per your edit... You say that the sourcepath will be the same as the classpath. Where did you get that from? Why would the default be to look for source files in the same folder as your class files?

Comment: That was what I originally tried (with the -cp). It doesn't compile on Mac.

Comment: @PhilAnderson See my edit, when I override the `CLASSPATH` using `-cp` option, `A.java` stops compiling. This pretty much confirms that `sourcepath` uses `CLASSPATH` as it's default value. I highly doubt that it should work differently on a Mac or any other OS for that matter since both the documentation and the `verbose` output from `javac` cannot be wrong. I recommend that you take a closer look and make sure that you are not missing anything.

Comment: And yet I've actually tried it on both Mac and Windows, and although I find it surprising, it IS different. I guess we'll agree to disagree on this. No harm done.

Comment: @PhilAnderson I don't disagree with you. I disagree that the documentation can be wrong. You can update your answer with your findings.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has to either find and successfully compile a source for B, or find a .class for B even if it's just an import. As opposed to loading, which is done dynamically.

Look in your output directory and you'll see that B has been compiled as well. It will be compiled even if in a different package, but you'll have to make it public to reference it from A.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Oracle javac docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCCHDGH)...

> If you set the -sourcepath option, then the compiler searches the
>   indicated path for source files. Otherwise, the compiler searches the
>   user class path for both class files and source files.
>   On Windows, the -sourcepath option seems to be set by default and your command works.

On my Mac though, it fails and gives following message...

```
A.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    B b;
    ^
  symbol:   class B
  location: class A
1 error
```

To get it to automatically look and compile source files of dependencies, you would need to use the -sourcepath option. e.g...

```
javac -sourcepath ./* A.java
```

Comment: See my answer. I believe the sourcepath defaults to `CLASSPATH` and chances are that you have `CLASSPATH` set on your machine.