# Java inheritance error: "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java

I am beginner to java!! I got `cannot find symbol` error in java. I google it but not found any satisfactory solution. Here is my `connect.java` class

```
public class connect
{
    static String JDBC_DRIVER; 
    static String DB_URL;
    static String USER;
   static String PASS;
 public connect(){
    JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 
    DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db";
    USER = "admin";
    PASS = "123";
 }
   public Connection openDbConnection(){
        Connection conn = null;
        try{
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
        }
        catch(SQLException se){
           se.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("successfully connected to db");
        return conn;
   }
```

And this is `query.java` class

```
public class query extends connect {
    Statement stmt;
    Connection connection;
    public query(){
        super();
        stmt = null;
        connection =null;
    }

    public void runquery(){

        connection=super.openDbConnection();
        System.out.println("Creating statement...");
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        String sql;
        sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
           int id  = rs.getInt("id");
           System.out.print("ID: " + id);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        query obj = new query(); 
        obj.runquery();
    }   
}
```

When i compile query.java through terminal `javac query.java`, i got error:

```
public class query extends connect {
                           ^
  symbol: class connect
src/database/query.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
        connection=super.openDbConnection();
                   ^
  symbol:   variable super
  location: class query
2 errors
```

both classes are in same directory. Can any one help me to fix this error???

Comment: are you sure your connect class compiles without errors?

Comment: Looks like your connect class is not in the build path.

Comment: Note: Java has coding conventions. Names of classes, interfaces and enums should start with a capital letter, like `Connect`, `ConnectToDatabase`. Variables and fields which are not constants should start with a lowercase letter, like `jdbcDriver`, `dbUrl` etc. Constants (either enum constants or `static final` variables are the only ones that are written in all-caps and have underscores between words, like `CONST_NAME`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 javac connect.java query.java
```

it should work.

Or you can try compiling your classes from parent directory of your package i.e. from `src` directory like below in my case

```
C:\..\YourProject\src>javac -cp . database\query.java
```

The link below explains the second approach which I discussed above.

### See Also

- [javac : Compiling a .java file which uses other classes in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475491/javac-compiling-a-java-file-which-uses-other-classes-in-it)
- [How does javac automatically compile dependencies of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527632/how-does-javac-automatically-compile-dependencies-of-a-class)

Comment: I added `}` to compile connect.java.

Comment: Thats why you are the Prince!

Comment: But a different error. Not a "Can not find symbol" in line 22.

Comment: thanks! it works but how to run it to show results on terminal

Comment: ok i got it!! thanks i am new in stackoverflow i don't have right to vote but my vote is with you

Comment: can you tell me why we compile like this " javac connect.java query.java"??? and any usefull source ??

Answer (score 0):

The class `connect` miss a `}` to compile, so the compiler use a older `connect.class`-file from a version he could compile before, a old version who did  not have the `openDbConnection`-Method. As long as the `connect.java` can not be compiled, he uses the old compiled version of `connect`.

Add a `}` to `connect.java` and the error in `query.java` will disappear

Comment: But a different error. Not a "Can not find symbol" in line 22.