# Compiling java class with javac doesn't work

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I want to compile my java class like that: `javac ResultSet.java`

But I get the following error:

```
ResultSet.java:5: error: package data does not exist
import data.Spieler;
       ^
ResultSet.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    private ArrayList<Spieler> meineSpieler = new ArrayList<Spieler>();
                      ^
symbol:   class Spieler
location: class ResultSet
ResultSet.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    public native Spieler[] getSpieler();
                  ^
symbol:   class Spieler
location: class ResultSet
ResultSet.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    public ArrayList<Spieler> getMeineSpieler() {
                     ^
symbol:   class Spieler
location: class ResultSet
ResultSet.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    private ArrayList<Spieler> meineSpieler = new ArrayList<Spieler>();
                                                            ^
symbol:   class Spieler
location: class ResultSet
```

How can I import the `spieler` class? Should I set the classpath or is there a other way to fix that?

Comment: looks like a problem with teh package... check that

Comment: "Should I set the classpath ...?" - exactly, how else should the compiler know which class to import (there might be several versions on your system)? Besides that you might want to consider using a build system like Gradle or Maven to facilitate that.

Comment: also, i´d recommend to use an `ide` in order to not care for things you don´t really want to care for (like packages while manually compiling)

Comment: so yes, you need to add `-cp <path-to-package-for-spieler>`

Comment: So I should use -cp <path to class spieler> <path to class JNIResultSet> ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does javac automatically compile dependencies of a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30527632/how-does-javac-automatically-compile-dependencies-of-a-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go one directory up and then compile it with

```
javac data/JNIResultSet.java
```

**Update:**
Ok, your class `JNIResultSet` is in package `model` and it uses other classes in package `data`.

Then your compile command should be as follows:

```
javac -cp . model/JNIResultSet.java
```

The `-cp .` part means, that your classpath includes the current directory. This is the root of your package hierarchy. So the compiler can find the *.java files in package `data` and compiles them also as needed.

You see, this can be very complicated. For more classes this will be nearly unmanageable. So you should really consider to use a build system like Ant, Maven or Gradle.

Comment: but JNIResultSet is in a other package then class `Spieler`

Comment: Ok, in what package is class `Spieler`? Use this path in the `javac` command.

Comment: I have 2 packages called `data` where the Spieler class is and `model` where the JNIResultSet class is

Comment: It is not really clear what you mean by 2 packages called data, but I updated my answer to reflect the package hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

use **`-classpath`** while compiling the file as 
`javac -classpath <path-to-dependent-classes> JNIResultSet.java`

It is required only when the `Spieler` is not on classpath!

for more help refer [javac oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new at this stuff. How would my javac look like if I want to compile class `JNIResultSet`? My project looks like that -> `src -> data package (contains person class) and model package(contains JNIResultSet)`

Comment: from `src` folder, run **`javac -classpath ./ model/JNIResultSet.java`**